# Variable handling between class and functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I am trying to run the script until a randomly generated number is not matching with the thread number. I am using multi-thread. (I just copied here one of them).

Everything did work well until I moved the randomnumbers() generator in a function. As long as the generated number was in the "runmain" function, it was fine.

```py
def randomnumbers():
    guessednumber = random.randint(1,101)
    return guessednumber

def runmain(number, guessednumber):
    while guessednumber!= number:    
        randomnumbers()
        if guessednumber == number:
            print(guessednumber)
            print(number)

class myClass1(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
        self.start()
    def run(self):
        while True:
            number = 1
            randomnumbers()
            runmain(number, guessednumber)

myClass1()
```

What I am missing?

Comment: `randomnumbers()` returns a number. You don't capture the return value. E.g. `guessednumber = randomnumbers()`.

Comment: You right! so basic. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you defined as `randomnumbers()` is a generator, thus it **returns** a value that needs to be captured (either assign it to variable or pass into a function as an argument).

You returning the variable `guessednumber` in function `randomnumbers()` doesn't actually return that variable, but returns its captured value (a random integer in this case).

```
def randomnumbers():
    return random.randint(1,101)  # Just return the value immediately without assigning to a varialble since it's not needed


def runmain(number, guessednumber):
    while guessednumber!= number:
        guessednumber = randomnumbers()  # Capture the returned value from randomnumbers() into the variable in comparison (guessednumber)
    print(guessednumber)  # No need to have an "if" statement here, since while loop will automatically break when (guessednumber==randomnumbers()) condition is satisfied
    print(number)


class myClass1(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
        self.start()
    def run(self):
        while True:
            number = 1
            runmain(number, randomnumbers())  # Passed the returned value from the function randomnumbers() as an argument in runmain()
```